# Use templates as a members when not all the details are known

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to specifiy a template as a member but not know all the details? Or rather how can I work around this.

Example doesn't work but might show you what I'm trying to achieve.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
   ///blah...
};

struct Bar {
    Foo* m_foo;
};
```

`Bar` in this case is a base class, and depending on the derived classes I wont know the full details of `Foo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either make `Bar` a template class as well so it can pass that template argument along to `Foo`, or else you can make all the `Foo<T>` variations inherit from a common interface (in C++, an interface is just an abstract class with no implementation, all members are pure virtual functions) and then `Bar` can point to that interface.

The first way is better if `Bar` is just going to provide some functionality which will be reused by a bunch of derived classes.

The second way is better if descendants of `Bar` are going to be used polymorphically.

Comment: There's a rather lengthy discussion about templates and their methods here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764912/dynamic-cast-ing-variable-arguments-to-templates .   He also wanted to do a Foo*, which is something you can't do with templates (unless it inherits from a common base).  But there's some good advice there on how to accomplish what I think you need.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for the background discussion.  I most definitely mentioned the possibility of using a common base, do you think that part of my answer is unclear?

Comment: I think your answer is fine (I upvoted you).  I just linked the other discussion because there's a lot more detail (in both the question and answers), including code examples.  I figured the additional reference could aid PhilCK (or anyone else encountering this page).

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above won't work, since whenever you use a C++ template you must specify what it's arguments are.  If you want to store a Foo of an unknown type, you can do so by parameterizing Bar over some type (for example, making it a template with type argument T), then having Bar store a Foo.  This contrasts with other languages like Java where code like what you have outlined above is legal because templates work differently in C++.  In particular, Java-style genetics just compile down to one concrete representation, then use runtime checks to verify that they're being used properly. C++ template instantiations all end up getting compiled down into separate code, and so the compiler has to be able to  infer at compile-time what the argument types are (so it knows what code to generate).